# How to determine the shape along which an object is moving

Tags: signal-analysis, shape-analysis

The object moves as it pleases and receives its GPS coordinates.
How to determine which shape the object is moving along?
For example, we accumulated 10 points, processed them and produced the result: the object moves in a straight line.
Then they accumulated 10 more points, processed and issued: the object changed direction by 20 degrees and moves in a straight line.
[image]

Comment: Hi! So, what's the specific question here?

Comment: @MarcusMüller How to determine which shape the object is moving along?

Comment: that's a bit too broad. What is a "shape", when you only have noisy points? Also, what have you researched so far?

Comment: @MarcusMüller a "shape" it is a "line", "circle".
If you don't understand a question then don't write any answers please

Comment: Um, this is how community self-moderation works here: Users give you feedback on your question in an attempt to help you improve it. No problem, I don't have to do that – vote to close as "needs more focus" and move on.

Comment: To support Marcus's comments that were meant to help, it would be easy to join the blue dots two-by-two in order. Then you could have a first zigzag, then two zigzags. Those are shapes as well. They would not be meaningful for your objective.  Maybe you think of a parametric shape (line, circle) but there are so many parametric shapes. By any three consecutive points, we could fit a circle.

Comment: You're effectively asking an algorithm to look at clouds and tell you what it sees. It's hard to quantify the shapeliness of a pattern without some form of visual intelligence. My recommendation would be to start off with a Kalman filter to eliminate measurement noise and maybe an additional low-pass filter to make your "shape" less jagged. Then I'd put this question to people who know a thing or two about computer vision and deep learning. You can train a neural net to recognize shapes you have predefined.

Comment: @AnalogEE , Yesterday was published the 55th edition of the TOP500 list - the rating of the most high-performance supercomputers in the world. I think your advice can be implemented with a simple supercomputer. You are a really cool advisor.

Comment: Nothing I just listed should exceed the power of a basic workstation or server depending on your update rate and the resolution of your map (which you can low-pass filter and downsample for the shape identification anyway). The filtering and deep learning might benefit from a GPU to accelerate them though.

Answer (score 1):

The best answer is to read this work on [Modeling and Estimation of the Trajectory of a moving Object](https://cyberleninka.ru/article/n/modelirovanie-i-otsenivanie-traektorii-dvizhuschegosya-obekta).

In this work, a linear discrete model of left / right circular motion with a given radius is constructed. 
A new algorithm for mathematical modeling of the trajectory of a moving object, consisting of segments of rectilinear and circular motion in conditions of incomplete noisy measurements, has been formulated and implemented.
 It is shown how to apply optimal discrete filtering algorithms to estimate such a trajectory.

Comment: Link-only answers are generally not very well-received, because they tend to defer answering the actual question to the linked resource. If possible, please describe how exactly the linked content can be applied to the original question, even if just briefly.

Comment: In this case, just linking doesn't work at all as answer on this site - the linked resource is in Russian, and hence can't be read by the majority of this site. Answers and questions are in English, so that this platform enables users to learn from each other. I don't know who upvoted this; they shouldn't have.